# Hall bigamy problem.

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

I'm looking for a rigorous proof for Hall's bigamy problem:

> Let $G$ a bipartite graph with sides $V$ and $U$. Prove that you can match
>   for any vertex in $V$ two vertices in $U$, that are matched only to it if and only if for any $X \subset V$ we have $|N_G(X)| \geq 2|X|$, where $N_G(X)$ is the neighbourhood of $X$ (according to Hall's marriage theorem).

I tried to duplicate the edges in $V$ and apply Hall's marriage theorem, meaning for any $v \in V$ create a $v'$ and connect it to the edges that $v$ is connected to in $U$.

I think that at least one of the sides is sort of trivial but I would love to hear other peoples opinion and get help with the other side or proving both sides if needed.
Thanks!

Comment: What is $NG(X)$?

Comment: The set of neighbours of subset X, according to Hall's theorem. editing...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application of Hall's marriage theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393208/application-of-halls-marriage-theorem)

Answer (score 1):

Assume $|N_G(X)|\ge2|X|$ for every $X\subseteq V$.
Consider the bipartite graph $G'$ with vertices $V\times\{1,2\}\cup U$ and an edge between $(v,i)$ and $u$ iff $G$ has an edge $vu$. We have the projection $\pi_1\colon V\times\{1,2\}\to V$.
Then for $X\subseteq V\times\{1,2\}$, we have $$|N_{G'}(X)|=|N_G(\pi_1(X))|\ge 2|\pi_1(X)|\ge |X|$$
and so by monogamic Hall, there exists a matching of $V\times\{1,2\}$ with $U$ in $G'$. This gives us a bigamic matching of $V$ and $U$ in $G$.

The other direction is trivial.